# Comment/Uncomment Chrome Developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, comments, development-environment

```
//Comment

//Ctrl+K,Ctrl+C (to comment code in Visual studio)
//Ctrl+K,Ctrl+U (to uncomment code in Visual studio)

//Ctrl+? (To Comment in Chrome Developer Tools)
//Ctrl+? (To Uncomment in Chrome Developer Tools)
```

I use [network mapping](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces) in Chrome Development Tools.
I want to comment/uncomment a block of code in javascript.
Is there a way on how to comment/uncomment JavaScript code in Chrome Developer Tools?
Thanks!

Comment: your question is not clear ? tell more about question.

Comment: Thanks, I will revise it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I can find Chrome currently doesn't currently have a shortcut (In the Elements panel) for this.

In the below keyboard shortcuts it says you can use "Ctrl + /" or "Cmd + /" to toggle a comment in the sources panel if thats of any help.

I believe I also read that "Ctrl + *" or "Cmd + *" may work if the above doesn't.

[Chrome Keyboard Shortcuts](https://web.archive.org/web/20221101233537/http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/)

[Chrome Keyboard Shortcuts Official](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/)